# java.lang.arrayindexOutOfBoundsEXCEPTION: 22

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

This question was posted in this OTN community thread: [Can getGeneratedKeys() be used when executing batches of statements?](https://community.oracle.com/thread/339649)

But unfortunately I didn't find the answers appropriate.

That thread is now locked, so I would like to start it again here.

This is a summary of the other thread:

> Can you retrieve keys generated by a batch of insert statements? The
>   following code produces an **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** from the
>   Oracle T4CNumberAccessor.unmarshalOneRow() method (see stack trace at
>   the bottom of this message).
>
> The code is:
>
> ```
> String sql = "INSERT INTO FOO (ID, NAME) VALUES (FOO_SEQ.NEXTVAL, ?)";
>  String generatedColumns[] = {"ID"};
>  PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql, generatedColumns);
>
> pstmt.setString(1, "A");
>  pstmt.addBatch();
>  pstmt.setString(1, "B");
>  pstmt.addBatch();
>  pstmt.setString(1, "C");
>  pstmt.addBatch();
>
> //EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE
>  pstmt.executeBatch();
> ```
>
> The exception is:
>
> ```
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 22
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CNumberAccessor.unmarshalOneRow(T4CNumberAccessor.java:190)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:610)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:955)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10580)
> ```

Comment: @are: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: No.
 Insert the data in the database correctly, but the error occurs.

Comment: This is also a parial copy of [this old thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2345922?start=0&tstart=0). You haven't explained why those threads haven't helped you. How about showing your code and the error you are getting, rather than referring to an old off-site link that doesn't tell us anything about your actual problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to specifically state what measures you have tried, particularly the `ExecutionContext` settings referenced in the last post of the thread you cited (`setBatchingLimit(int)` and `setBatching(bool)`). A [mcve] showing what *you* have attempted would also be helpful.

Comment: I want run INSERT commands as ExecuteBatch and finally get the IDs of new records. please guide me .

Comment: [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/jdbcvers.htm#JJDBC28099) says this isn't supportd: "You cannot combine auto-generated keys with batch update."

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: Thanks @Gord Thompson .this is comment was very helpful .